# Named array element used in function definition

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, implicit-conversion

Recently I discovered that this syntax works in JavaScript (Chrome 53):

```
function foo([param1]) { // Function argument is declared as array and param1 is used as variable? What is the name of this syntax?
  console.log(param1); 
}

foo(['TestParameter1']); // Case 1 - works. Output: TestParameter1
foo('TestParameter1');   // Case 2 - works??? Why? Output: TestParameter1
foo(123);                // Case 3 - does not work - VM860:1 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function(…)

Result => TestParameter1 // this is the result
```

I see that param1 can be used as variable that references item with index 0 in the first argument (declared as array).

My questions are:

1) How is this syntax named (the [param1] part that lets you use param1 as variable)?

2) Why does "Case 2" work? Is there any automatic conversion?

Comment: how is `item1` defined?

Comment: @Redu it is defined as in the example: function foo([param1]) {}

Comment: [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: It won’t work with `item1`, but with `param1`. Also the second case actually returns `T`.

Comment: @Xufox my fault - I corrected it

Comment: @Xufox I suspected Destructuring, but the documentation doesn't mention it applies to function arguments? Or I can't find it?

Comment: @iPath ツ Destructuring applies to all assignments. In this particular case the argument you pass to the function at the time you invoke it gets assigned to the argument expression in the function's definition.

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that Strings are implicitly arrays.

Comment: @Tobiq `[param1]` destructuring will just grab the first item of any primitive or object with an iterator function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Xufox pointed out, this works because of [`destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) ([array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring), to be more specific). Your second example works because a [string is an array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access), so you get `T`, which is `param1[0]`. Numbers are not arrays (or even array-like), so the the engine fails to destructure the argument.

If you coerce your number to a string it will work:

```
foo((123).toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be destructuring as @Xufox correctly pointed out.

Function parameters can in fact have destructuring:

1. go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
2. Search for this text: Pulling fields from objects passed as function parameter
3. Now the above shows an example of another kind of destructuring, example given below:

   ```
   function userId({id}) {
     return id;
   }

   var user = { 
     id: 42, 
     displayName: "jdoe"
   };

   console.log("userId: " + userId(user)); // "userId: 42"
   ```

however, I assume it applies to this as well:

```
function foo([param1]) {
  console.log(param1);
}
```

Difference between integers and strings in this behaviour:

```
console.log('123'); //works, outputs 1, '123' = ['1', '2', '3'] of chars
console.log(['123']); //works, outputs 123
console.log([123]); //works, outputs 123
console.log(123); //error
```

In the above example, since strings are nothing but an array of chars, its perfectly fine that it works actually.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as said by those brilliant folks above. Here's how the computer reads it:

foo('testParamater1') = foo(['testParamater1']);

but...

foo(123) = foo([[1,2,3]);

Unfortunately for your specific use case, not the same. Sorry!